# Как инициализировать переменную класса результатом функции в c#?

Tags: c#

Ошибка  1   Недопустимая лексема "=" в объявлении класса, структуры или интерфейса
Ошибка  2   Метод должен иметь тип возвращаемого значения

```
class Model
{
    DataTable dtSurface = new DataTable();
    dtSurface = TableXML();// тут выдает ошибку

    private DataTable TableXML()
    {
        //создаём таблицу
        DataTable dtXML = new DataTable();
        //создаём три колонки
        DataColumn a0 = new DataColumn("a0", typeof(Double));
        DataColumn a1 = new DataColumn("a1", typeof(Double));
        DataColumn a2 = new DataColumn("a2", typeof(Double));
        DataColumn a11 = new DataColumn("a11", typeof(Double));
        DataColumn a22 = new DataColumn("a22", typeof(Double));
        DataColumn a12 = new DataColumn("a12", typeof(Double));
        //DataColumn p = new DataColumn("p", typeof(Double));
        //добавляем колонки в таблицу
        dtXML.Columns.Add(a0);
        dtXML.Columns.Add(a1);
        dtXML.Columns.Add(a2);
        dtXML.Columns.Add(a11);
        dtXML.Columns.Add(a22);
        dtXML.Columns.Add(a12);

        return dtXML;
    }

    private void FillListCor(double[] A,int num)
    {
            dtSurface = TableXML();// тут не выдает ошибку
            DataRow newRow = null;
            newRow = dtSurface.NewRow();

            if(A.Length != 0) 
            {
                newRow = dtSurface.NewRow();
                newRow["a0"] = A[0];
                newRow["a1"] = A[1];
                newRow["a2"] = A[2];
                newRow["a11"] = A[3];
                newRow["a22"] = A[4];
                newRow["a12"] = A[5];
                dtSurface.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }

     }
}
```

Comment: @koks_rs Как это сделать? И почему в 1 случае ошибка выходит а во втором нет(и все нормально заполняется)

Comment: потому что в шарпе нельзя вызывать функции вне тела других функций. Вне функциий можно лишь инициализировать объекты вызывая их конструктор, вот так например `new DataTable();` ну или конечно завая напрямую, к примеру `int myvar = 10;`

Comment: @koks_rs Спасибо за информацию, не знал об этом.

Comment: Дайте вопросу нормальное название

Answer (score 3):

В шарпе нельзя вызывать функции вне тела других функций. Вне функциий можно лишь инициализировать объекты вызывая их конструктор, вот так например `new DataTable();` ну или конечно задавая напрямую, к примеру `int myvar = 10`

Создайте [конструктор по умолчанию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/k6sa6h87.aspx) и в нем инициализируйте переменную `dtSurface`.

```
class Model
{
   DataTable dtSurface;

   public Model(){
       dtSurface = TableXML();
   }


   private DataTable TableXML()
   {
      //.......
   }

}
```

Comment: Вообще говоря, можно вызвать статический метод класса при инициализации полей. Т.е. если объявить метод TableXML() статическим, то конструкция DataTable dtSurface = TableXML() будет вполне легальна.

Comment: @AleksandrZharinov, легальна и бессмысленна :) Это не в стиле ООП.

Comment: Я лишь хотел указать на возможность. Использовать данную возможность или нет - дело за автором.